# 'Project' support for Emacs

Tags: emacs

A while ago I saw something go by for 'search in project' etc support in Emacs where the definition of a project was simply looking from the current directory up til a .git or other source control directory was found.

I unfortunately didn't bookmark the project as I was off in Smalltalk land and didn't need Emacs at the time. I'd really appreciate pointers to the specific project I'm vaguely referencing or one that does the same thing. I've looked at eproject which seems close, but isn't quite what I'm remembering.

Comment: This might also help: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I was looking for, I finally found.

Textmate minor mode:

https://github.com/defunkt/textmate.el/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375738/emacs-recursive-project-search).  It sounds like what you're looking for is [find-file-in-project.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFileInProject).  The [EMACS Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SiteMap) is usually a good source for this kind of question.

Comment: i spent a couple hours tonight digging around in my bookmarks and on the emacs wiki. i also came across the SO question and find-file-in-project.el and neither is ringing the bell. the big thing i remember about what i'm looking for was it was hardwired to be based on source control 'artifacts' like a .git directory etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [eproject](https://github.com/jrockway/eproject) and its `eproject-find-file` and/or `eproject-grep` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I use TAGS for my project, and recently wrote this answer for [`igrep-in-tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474583/help-writing-emacs-lisp-for-emacs-etags-search/4479830#4479830), which does  a regexp search through all the files in the TAGS and gives the output in a *compilation* style buffer.