# Finding files using icicles in Emacs under Windows 7

Tags: search, emacs, bookmarks, locate, icicles

The short version of the question: how can I get [`icicles`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) to search usefully for files in directories and subdirectories, even if only given a partial match of the filename?

EDIT: The short answer is to use `icicle-locate-file` in the top level of your directory and use S-Tab (shift-tab) to begin completion rather than plain tab. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18935301/952708).

Just as an addendum, I gave up on `icicles` after this as it took about 10 seconds to find files in the (large) directory tree in question each time I used `icicle-locate-file`. There may be a way round this delay, perhaps by creating and sets of files 'gathered' by `icicles`, but I began to feel that the potential benefits were being eroded by the up-front costs of working this out and by the costs of keeping the file sets updated. As the author of `icicles` points out below, access to *nix's `locate` command would allow me to use `icicle-locate`, which is quicker than `icicle-locate-file`. However, I run on Windows and the Everything utility [doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851372/emacs-anything-and-the-everything-search-tool-under-windows-7). So, back to copious use of IDO and bookmarks that expand to `dired` buffers.

==========

The longer version... As Emacs (24.3.1) is now my main development environment I have been exploring ways of improving my efficiency, particularly regarding filename completion for some time now. Several excellent answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396967/emacs-what-are-good-tactics-for-navigating-directories-and-opening-files) pointed me to [`ido-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) and [`dired-x`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredExtra), both of which I am now using.

Another great recommendation was Emacs' [bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookMarks). In particular, defining `dired` buffers as bookmarks and jumping to them using `C-x r b mybook1` or even calling `C-x r b` from the `C-x C-f` minibuffer ([this page was helpful](http://scottfrazersblog.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/emacs-using-bookmarked-directories.html)) are two very useful strategies.

A couple of people mentioned [`anything`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) and its successor [`helm`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm). I have been unable to get the file location part of either package working on Windows 7. Apparently they depend on the command line version of [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com) but this fails for me, as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851372/emacs-anything-and-the-everything-search-tool-under-windows-7), to which there were some helpful responses but no definitive answers. It seems that it works smoothly on *nix but there's not much discussion of `helm-locate` etc on Windows. So that counts out `helm` and `anything` for filename completion.

Which brings me to icicles. In a question about [making find-file search in subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995303/emacs-how-to-make-find-file-search-in-subdirectories) the asker commented that they had taken a look at "ido and icicles, but they seem to work shallowly, only within current directory".

In response to this came a comment on icicles: "you can search for any file on your system, if you want, matching any part of the file name and path" with a pointer to a page on [Icicles file name input](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input). While I appreciate the considerable effort that has gone the help pages for icicles, I didn't find this one very useful because it consisted largely of a list of descriptions of icicles functions. What would be useful to me is a tutorial that walks you through finding files.

Let's assume the following.

- I am running a Windows 7 installation of Emacs 24.3.1.
- I have a top-level directory containing some files and folders. In this case it is `c:/iciclestest/`.
- I know there's a file somewhere in this section of the tree that has "grob" as part of the filename.
- I want to use icicles to find this file. I have put `(require 'icicles)` and `(icy-mode 1)` in my init file.

So, off we go. Start Emacs in the scratch buffer. Hit C-x C-f. I get a `File or directory` prompt, with a purple plus sign to the left that I think indicates that this is one of icicles' [multi-commands](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands).
[image: ice]

Hitting tab gets me this mini-frame, showing me the contents of the current directory.
[image: ice]

I hit tab on the `folder1` subdirectory and icicles shows me the contents of that, as one would expect.
[image: ice]

You can see a couple of files with "grob" in the name.
Right, C-g to clear everything then C-x C-f again. Enter 'grob'. I get a "no prefix completions" message. This surprised me a little because I expected icicles to have some kind of whizzy fuzzy matching like ido-mode.
[image: ice]

Okay, maybe I need a different command. Let's try `M-x icicle-locate-file`, which gives me this prompt:
[image: ice]

If I enter 'grob' and hit confirm I just get a new file, as per below.
[image: ice]

To recap: what I'd like to be able to do is enter a string and have icicles go and look for files or folders containing that string. My main dev folder has many dozens of directories and thousands of files so a quick find within Emacs would be a godsend.

I realise that the `locate` command doesn't exist on Windows so functionality will be in some ways limited, but I would have thought a recursive search of files and subdirs from the current dir based on a user-entered string would be straightforward. What am I missing? Am I going about this the right way? Can this be done in icicles?

Comment: I would really suggest to use ido-mode, and in some cases Dired is useful. `ido` really is better than icicles.

Comment: Well, a variety of opinion is healthy. I have found `ido` useful but it was because I felt I wanted a bit more that I looked at icicles. So far the latter looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to read the Icicles doc a bit more: use `S-TAB` instead of `TAB` for [apropos](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions) (regexp or substring) completion.  That is apparently all you want here: match `grob` as a substring.  (No need for any fuzzy matching for that.)
2. Since you want files matching `grob` anywhere under that directory, use `icicle-locate-file`. Give it that directory as the starting point.  (And since you want to match `grob` anywhere in the file name, use `S-TAB` for completion.)
3. Icicles does provide "whizzy fuzzy matching like ido-mode" (in fact a lot [whizzier](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion)).  Ido's "flex" matching is the same as Icicles's "scatter" matching.
4. You can set the kind of completion you want to be one of the fuzzy-matching types.  In the minibuffer, `C-(` cycles among the prefix-completion methods.  `M-(` cycles among the apropos-completion methods.  True fuzzy matching is a prefix completion method.  Flex/scatter matching is a poor man's fuzzy matching, and it is an apropos completion method (so use `M-(` to cycle to it).  To change the default matching, so you need not cycle to get the ones you prefer, customize option `icicle-S-TAB-completion-methods-alist` or `icicle-TAB-completion-methods`.

Comment: I still feel that the icicle docs are thorough but not necessarily helpful for a new user - others agree with me and express their views [rather more forcefully](http://xah-forum.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/icicles-saga-tech-geeking-story.html). Anyway, thanks for the above, it is indeed what I needed. I do find that `icicle-locate-file` takes 7-10 seconds to gather the files in my main directory and this doesn't seem to change through the session. Is there any way around this? I know I can save sets, but the gathering process kicks in *before* I get a chance to specify a set to retrieve.

Comment: 1. You are welcome to your opinion, of course.  FWIW, that post from XahLee is from 2009, and he admits that he "spen[t] 10 secs on the home page, came away not knowing what it actually do[es], and left."  Not much of a witness. 2. As the doc says, and as you repeat, you can save any set of file locations --- save all on your drive if you like.  If you had the OS command `locate` then you could use `icicle-locate`, which uses the cache computed by `locate` asynchronously (e.g., periodically).  (You could also launch Emacs periodically and have it save an updated list.)

Comment: You use "SlowLearner" as your user name. Dunno how you mean that, and anyway, even if you are, there is nothing wrong with being a slow learner. I recommend reading the [nutshell](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View) description of Icicles, to start with. That should at least have gotten you past any confusion about `TAB` and `S-TAB'. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer about `icicle-locate-file`, you can find files that are in *marked Dired subdirectories*, and their marked subdirectories, etc. *recursively*, using `M-+ C-F` (command `icicle-visit-marked-file-of-content-recursive`), if you use both [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) and [***Dired+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DiredPlus).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19047272/729907) provides the details.